# React. Теория. Путаница с определениями элементов и компонентов

Tags: reactjs

Допустим, это `render()` метод некоего компонента `Component1`

```
render() {
    const list = this.state.array.map(
                      item => ( <Component2 key={item.id}/> ));

    return (<div> { list } </div>);
}
```

В моём понимании, компонент это сама функция или класс, которые его определяют.
Но мне нужно показать иерархию элементов и компонентов в этом коде.

Я бы сказал так, `Component1` состоит из элемента `list`, который включает в себя набор компонентов `Component2`, который в свою очередь также состоит из каких-то элементов.

Напрашивается вопрос, а разве элементы могут включать в себя компоненты?
Может быть вопрос глупый, но я бы хотел точно знать что здесь что.

Comment: Когда вы пишете в `jsx` `<div className="sidebar" />`, например, то Babel компилирует это все в `React.createElement('div', {className: 'sidebar'}, null)`, т.е. элементы уже не совсем элементы, а объекты js. Компонент это по сути такой же объект с кучей вложенных объектов через `children`. Когда мы якобы вставляем компонент в элемент, мы втавляем один объект в другой, что совершенно нормально. Реакту не нужен текстовый `html` ибо ему ещё нужно виртуальный дом строить и работать с ним как можно быстрее, что сложно, если постоянно парсить `html`. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: Оформишь в ответ?

Comment: А как это сделать?